# Union of Two Independent Events

Tags: probability

I have a following question from a GRE test prep book:

In a probability experiment, $G$ and $H$ are independent events. The probability that $G$ will occur is $r$, and the probability that $H$ will occur is $s$, where both $r$ and $s$ are greater than $0$.

In the answer, the probability that either $G$ will occur or $H$ will occur, but **not** both is defined as: $r + s - 2rs$.

I thought the union of two events A and B is given as $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$ which in this question equates to $r+s-rs$. My questions are: Which one is correct? Does the definition of union include the probability that both events will occur?

Comment: Well note that for independent events you have $P(A)P(B)=P(A)\cap{}P(B)$ so both are correct. The probability that both will occur is implied by the inclusion exclusion principle.

Comment: Do not confuse the phrase "*A or B (which includes possibility of both)*" with the phrase "*Either A or B (but not both)*".  The first event is represented by $A\cup B$.  The second event is represented by $A\triangle B$ or as $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$ or as $(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$.  The question asks you to find the probability of this *second* phrase, not the first.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, the phrase "*Either A or B*" should strictly imply not both, but sadly language evolves and people misuse phrases so it unfortunately is used by people incorrectly to mean "*A or B*."  This problem however strictly points out the *not both* aspect.  Computer scientists might use "XOR" in place of "Either...or" but it is not common yet to hear it in conversation.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you! Out of curiosity, what is the mathematical term for $A△B$?

Comment: The [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the definition of union includes cases in which both occur. Thus both statements are correct: the probability of $A \cup B$ (by definition including cases both occur) is $r+s-rs$, and to get the probability that one but not both occurs, subtract the probability that both occur ($rs$) to get $r+s-2rs$

Comment: Makes sense thank you!